# Should sleeping interrupted thread reinterrupt itself if it was awaken?

Tags: java, multithreading

The thread is working until it is interrupted but it is sleeping from time to time:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        //A TASK HERE
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 + Math.random() * 100));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupt(); //it was interrupted while it was sleeping
        }
    }
}
```

The intention is to kill the thread by interrupting it. Can I reinterrupt itself like I did or I should set a flag `stop = true` within the exception clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch the interruption outside the loop:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            //A TASK HERE
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 + Math.random() * 100));
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Irrespective of where you catch the `InterruptedException`, it's a good idea to reinterrupt the current thread if you've not *really* handled it, and you can't simply throw the `InterruptedException` (e.g. because it's inside a method which doesn't declare that it throws `InterruptedException` or `Exception` or `Throwable`).

This allows callers of the `run()` method to know that execution was interrupted, so *they* can stop what they are doing too.

The main case where you may decide not to re-interrupt the thread is if you are writing some sort of threading framework (like Executors), where you reuse the previously-interrupted thread to do the next task.

Comment: The main case for not re-interrupting can be generalized to any kind of operation where you’re expecting the current task to be potentially interrupted, to stop that particular task but continue with the next (usually unrelated) task.